# jQuery UI Sortable: Scroll entire page as well as container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two lists of elements, and I have enabled jQuery UI sortable on both of them.  I used the `connectWith` option to enable me to drag between the two lists.

One list has a lot of elements in it, so I added `overflow-y: scroll` to it, but when I try to grab an element from that list and drag it to the other, it only scrolls the list, not the entire page.

I made a jsFiddle demo (http://jsfiddle.net/MCcuc/).  Scroll down, and try to move `Item Q` (drag it by the gray bar on top of the box) from the red list into the green list.  You'll see the red list scrolls, but the page does not.  How can I scroll the whole page as well as the list?

I'm just enabling `sortable` without many options:

```
$('.sort').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sort',
    handle: '.handle'
});
```

Comment: I think this has something to do with the second list being scrollable.  Notice that if you start off and drag out of the first list into the second list it scrolls the page like you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's indeed a conflict with scrollable overflow. The draggable helper element is constrained to its parent in that case, probably because trying to "get outside" the parent only results in enlarging its scrollable region.

A workaround is to pass a `helper` function that clones the dragged element and reparents it under the page body. This way, the draggable helper element will be outside of its original parent from the start, and therefore will scroll the entire page:

```
$(".sort").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sort",
    handle: ".handle",
    helper: function(event, element) {
        return element.clone().appendTo("body");
    }
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle demonstrating this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhamidi/MCcuc/2/).

Comment: Cool, this seems to work.  I found a weird bug though.  If you try to drag to the end of the green list, it jumps back into the red list.  If you drop it anywhere else, it works.

Comment: Indeed. Apparently the two sortables are competing to be the drop target, and distance to the helper looks like the determinator.